# Leaflet.js/Mapbox.js On Library Ready event?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

Is there a way to know when the  Leaflet.js or Mapbox.js library is loaded & ready? I'm running into trouble where the library hadn't loaded yet when my DOMContentLoaded event fires.

Other libraries, (for example Facebook's JS API), let you define a function, like window._onFacebookready, and when they load they call that. Does Leaflet or Mapbox.js do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too be short, there isn't. You could however, hook into the `onload` event of the `script` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" onload="console.log(L)" src="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Too bad! I took a look through Leaflet's code this morning and there's absolutely nothing to latch onto.

I'll have to use onload, plus some readystatchange magic for IE8, and hope that the onload fires *after* the loaded JS is executed.